# JSON.stringify - how to use it in Symfony2

Tags: php, javascript, json, symfony, twig

Sorry for the stupid question, but I don't know a thing about JavaScript. I'm trying to use JSON.stringify to make an array looking pretty and be easy to read.

I tried this in controller:

```
    $metadata = '{"hello":"world", "Test":["hello"]}';
    $data = json_encode($metadata);

    return $this->render('AcmeQuotesBundle:Home:metadata.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
```

and this in template:

```
   <script>
        var obj = {{ data }}

        document.body.innerHTML = "";
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)));
    </script>
```

but I get a white screen.

How I can make it work?

Comment: SyntaxError: syntax error
http://localhost/my-quotes/web/app_dev.php/metadata/1
Line 19

Comment: Semicolon missing? `var obj = {{ data }};`

Comment: No :( it is pointing to  &quot; in this: `var obj = &quot;{\&quot;hello\&quot;:\&quot;world\&quot;, \&quot;Test\&quot;:[\&quot;hello\&quot;]}&quot;;`

Comment: Try this: `var obj = {{ data|raw }};`

Comment: Now I get the text, but it's on one line, I would like to print it like this http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/HZPVL/

Comment: Why? for js interpreter it makes no difference if it is in one line or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below

```
var obj = {{ data|raw }};
```

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify({{ data|raw }}, null, 4));